# Handle a JSON Response with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, alamofire

I have a problem I want to handle a JSON Response with Alamofire in Swift
So I found this answer on Stackoverflow unfortunately this post is a few days older.
My question is how can I receive the data from Alamofire on first button press (without swiftyJSON).
I hope someone could help me.

This is the link I found on Stackoverflow.

[Handle JSON Response with Alamofire in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956445/handle-json-response-with-alamofire-in-swift)

Comment: Read the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-json-handler).

Comment: please give me a little hint

Comment: I'm sorry ... maybe I'm stupid but I don't know what you mean :/

Answer (score 3):

this is a small example.

This is what the JSON returns if it fails json_file.json

```
{ "transaction":"error" }
```

This is what the JSON returns if its success json_file.json

```
{ "transaction":"success" }
```

this is the code , you must add your own URL that will return any of those json responses. (example only)

```
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://myjsonexamplewebsite.com/json_file.json", parameters:nil)

            .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in

                //println(JSON)
                var response = JSON as NSDictionary

                var transaction = response.objectForKey("transaction") as String

                if transaction == "success" {

                    NSLog("JSON response was successfull")

                }
                else {

                    NSLog("JSON response had an Error")
                }

        }
```