# Parsing and Storing JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

cI'm trying to, with Swift 2 and Alamofire, make a request to an API, and then store the data so that I can use it in another function.

For example, this is my code below, and I'm trying to figure out how to assign it to a variable so that I can use it later in the file. I've tried Google'ing and trying a bunch of options and I haven't got anywhere in the past 3 hours.

```
func getToken() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://somesite.com/ping").responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
    }
}
```

So as we can see, we have the response, but could we assign the contents of it to a variable so we can use it in a function such as `pryResponse`?

```
func pryResponse() {
    print(response)
}
```

Something similar to that, but an actual variable.

Comment: Ready on properties and data models.

Comment: @zaph What do you mean? Can you explain and show a few examples please?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. The syntax changed a bit with the latest release.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://livewx.tv/ping").responseJSON(){
                (_, json, result) in
                switch result {

                case .Success:
                    let json = result.value!
                    let stuff = json["results"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                    //stuff now holds a dictionary with the json
                case .Failure(_,  _):
                    //Error
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this but there's some issues. I'm fairly new so I'm not the best at describing this yet, but here are the errors: http://d.pr/i/tse3

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about no code being present in the error case, add a print statement or anything else and see if it goes away. Of course you should handle the error , but it looks like as long as you have code there it'll stop complaining

Comment: Yeah, adding a print statement under .Failure fixed the small error, this one is still there though: http://d.pr/i/sFkj.

Comment: Are you sure you're on the latest Alamo fire release?

Comment: I'm on ~>3.0 (I'm pretty sure it's the latest)

Comment: This answer is valid for `Alamofire 2.0`

Comment: @irealme so I would have to downgrade? If so there has to be a way to get this to work with the latest release.

Comment: @Craytor no you can also do the same with 3.0 too. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33130575/3734028

Comment: @IRealMe Right, I've seen that one yesterday. Can I still do the same setup if I'm using it directly in a ViewController? Or does it have to be in a class?

Comment: @Craytor you can do it directly too I guess

Comment: @Irealme Okay thanks for the response. I'll try it here tonight and get back to you about how it goes.