# Converting DataResponse<String> to a usable type

Tags: json, swift, type-conversion, alamofire

I have a POST request that is illustrated below. I need some help on how to be able to use the response data. The response I am getting is in a form of a dictionary. What is the best practice to use here? The error message I am getting is:

> Cannot assign value of type 'DataResponse' to type 'String'

```
func getRequest(){
    let urlString = "http://scissors.pythonanywhere.com/getRequest"
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["date": self.weekDays[self.itemSelectedIndex]],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseString {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)
            var backToString = String(data: response, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?

            break
        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `self.bookings = response as! String` but it gives me a warning saying it will fail. Also tried this: [Alamofire in Swift: converting response data in usable JSON dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613683/alamofire-in-swift-converting-response-data-in-usable-json-dictionary?rq=1) with no luck.

***EDIT***

This is the print i get from response.

```
SUCCESS: {
    "10:00" =     {
        booked = false;
        name = "";
        number = "";
    };
    "10:30" =     {
        booked = false;
        name = "";
        number = "";
    };
    "11:00" =     {
        booked = false;
        name = "";
        number = "";
    };
}
```

Comment: What happens when you do `.responseJson` instead of `.responseString`? Also, what do you get when you print response.result?

Comment: Changed to .responseJson and it is looking way better thank you for that but i still need to be able to assign it to a variable i create in swfit to be able to use it in other places. Check edit from the print result @LulzCow

Comment: Don't go the `responseJSON` route, it will clutter your code with optionals and casts to no end. I would stay with `responseString` and check out [this blog post](https://grokswift.com/rest-with-alamofire-swiftyjson/) for an example. Basically it boils down to use `if let value = response.result.value { print(value) }` to get your `String`. From there you should use the `Codable` protocol in order to get decent Swift-objects. If you post the JSON (the above is a linearised `NSDictionary` instead) we would be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually ended up using this method which was very simple and easy. In my case bookings was declared like this:  `var bookings: NSDictionary = [:]`

```
func getRequest(){

    let urlString = "http://scissors.pythonanywhere.com/getRequest"
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["date": self.weekDays[self.itemSelectedIndex]],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            self.bookings = JSON as! NSDictionary

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have the JSON representation, you should be able to do something like this:

```
if let dict = response as? [String:Any]{
    if let obj = dict["10:00"] as? [String:Any]{
         let booked = obj["booked"] as? Bool ?? false
         print("booked: \(booked)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this warning when using your method.: Cast from 'DataResponse<Any>' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Comment: @EmbeddedOS try casting `response.result as? [String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import SwiftyJSON

let json = JSON(response.result.value)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24128705)

Comment: Funny you say that because I had this exact same issue and solved it with those exact steps